# Install ROS on 11.04 Natty

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, rosinstall, ubuntu-natty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble installing on 11.04 using these [directions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source). rosinstall returns errors about missing some library so I install the library, run it again and get a new library missing. I think the directions page should be updated to reflect that it doesn't work with Natty.

How should I go about installing on Natty?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10011/install-ros-on-11.04-natty/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-05-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-21**:
Vote to close: duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/618/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-1104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of June 1, ROS is now updated to work on 11.04 Natty:
http://www.ros.org/news/2011/06/ros-packages-now-available-for-ubuntu-natty.html

Installation instructions can be found here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) with karma: 283 on 2011-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6